tableoffiguresandtables
I want to make

listoffigures
listoftables
listoofgraphes

all of them as in the image below.
This is my tex code:
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{xcolor,graphicx,lipsum}
\usepackage{lipsum} % for  dummy text
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\DeclareNewTOC[
  type=graph,
  name=Graph,
  listname=List de graphs,
  float=yes
]{grp}
\renewcommand*{\listoffigures}{\listoftoc[\textcolor{green}{\listfigurename}]{lof}}
\renewcommand*{\listoftables}{\listoftoc[\textcolor{red!90!black!50}{\listtablename}]{lot}}
\renewcommand*{\listofgraphs}{\listoftoc[\textcolor{red!40!blue!80}{List des graphs}]{grp}}
% optional
\DeclareCaptionFont{blue}{\bfseries\color{blue}}
\captionsetup[graph]{labelfont=blue}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables
\listofgraphs

\chapter{A test chapter}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\newpage
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\chapter{Begining to learn desin with html and som ather text to  span more than one line}

\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}
\begin{graph} [h]

 \caption{(short) caption that goes to the lot}
 
\end{graph}


\begin{graph}[h]
\centering (Another plot) \caption{Another  float for a graph.}
\end{graph}

\begin{graph}[h]
\centering (Another plot) \caption{Another  float for a graph.}
\end{graph}
\begin{graph}[h]
\centering (Another plot) \caption{Another  float for a graph.}
\end{graph}
\begin{graph}[h]
\centering (Another plot) \caption{Another  float for a graph.}
\end{graph}

\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{figure}
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\begin{table}
 \caption{A float for a graph.}
\end{table}
\end{document}



What is the question here? Are you trying to produce that output? Trying to change it? Or what? What does this have to do with comma-separated lists? Please don't add arbitrary tags. Please edit your title to something meaningful.

so sory I'm a beginner in this  web cit

نعم انا اريد اخراج قائمة الصور وقائمة الجداول وقائمة الرسومات البيانية مثل النموذج اعلاه هل من مساعدة

(DeepL powered translation of above comment: "Yes, I want to output a list of images, a list of tables and a list of charts like the example above.")
